where is the correct place to add a surface view dynamically in camera 2 api
I have custom view and in that i have a surface view and on the surfaceview camera preview is being display
where should surface view should be added
i m adding it in onAttachedWindow but i dont want that
may be on the constructor of my custom view
is it ok ?
 @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
     super.onAttachedToWindow();
       _surface = Injector.getInjector(getContext().getApplicationContext()).getSurfaceView();
        addView(_surface, 0);
            SurfaceHolder holder = _surface.getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this);
            setHolderPushBuffers(holder);
            getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(_globalLayoutListener);
}

